# About google tag manager

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using google tag manger, and I have created container and tag rules, also placed the code into my webpage.

I am not sure how many times tag was fired? How and where can I see the tag fired reports?

Please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/12/30/seo-reporting-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Very useful one. Thanks, I need to fired multiple urls (It around 3000+). How can i use it. Because of i am new one for using GTM. Please advice me.

Comment: Hi @SyedQarib, I have tried and implemented that, just a clarification need, when will we see the reports in landing page? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download the Google Tag Assistant and in settings change from the default simple to the detailed view. This will give you details regarding the tags on all of your pages, and not only includes information on GTM tags, but other tags like remarketing on your page as well.

Also, when you have created and saved your container go to the debug mode and then back to your pages that you want to check tags on. Refresh the page and you will be able to see which tags fire for that container on which pages. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have refer the link and i did. [link](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/12/30/seo-reporting-google-tag-manager/#sr=so&m=r&cp=%28sfgfssbm%29&ct=/rvftujpot/24908935/bcpvu-hpphmf-ubh-nbobhfs-tmc&ts=1406022182) . And also i have checked with Google Tag Assitant. where can see the details of reports. I cannot find anything. Please explain in details. Thanks

Comment: In GTM use the preview mode debug option, and reload your webpage. The tags that have fired on the page should be listed in a window below your webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The GTM preview and debug feature was a life saver for me. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2695660?hl=en. I'll add on to what GoHikeGo said... it shows you the events that happen and if tags are fired due to those events. It tells you why they did or did not fire. Plus, it shows you the macro and dataLayer values for each event. Very handy. Would not have been able to solve my problem without it.